# Regex for fixing YAML strings

Tags: regex, yaml

I am trying to create a bunch of YAML files, mostly composed of strings of text. Now when using apostrophes in words, they must be escaped by typing a double apostrophe, because I’m using apostrophes to wrap the strings.

I want to create a regex that will check for apostrophes in the text that aren’t double. What I have is this:

`^([^'\n]*?)'(([^'\n]*?)'(?!')([^'\n]+?))*?'$\n`

https://regex101.com/r/v4nUTn/3

My issue is that as soon as my string has a double apostrophe, but also has an apostrophe which isn’t a double apostrophe, it doesn’t match because my negative lookahead doesn’t match as soon as it sees the double apostrophe. (for example the string `t''e'st` won’t match even though it is missing a double apostrophe after the `e`)

How can I make it so that my negative lookahead will not fail as soon as it sees one double apostrophe?

Comment: I removed my comment as another read of your question made my suggestion pointless.

Comment: Which language do you use? You might really be looking for a parser instead which is able to allow some ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work:

```
\w'\w
```

Test [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/RRMxMs/1).

Comment: This is great, but it isn’t the full answer I’m looking for. I need the regex to be foolproof. For example, if I have a triple apostrophe or if I have an apostrophe at he beginning of a string, this regex won’t work.

Comment: Then your problem is seriously under-stated. You did not say anything about triple apostrophes. Or single apostrophes at the beginning - how do they look, give an example. Please refine and extend your question, to reflect everything you need / want.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe an expression similar to

```
('[^'\r\n]*'|[^\r\n\w']+)|([\w']*)
```

would be an option to look into.

---

If the second capturing group returns true, then the string is undesired.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/U1XKVr/1). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/U1XKVr/1debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to do this in two steps.

For example, if every 'candidate' value looks like this: `- 'something here'` (where you want to test the apostrophes in the `something here` content of the string, then first isolate out that content via:

`/^\s*- '(.+)'$/im`

And then make sure all apostrophe's appear as you want them to appear within match group 1 of the result.

Then, replace the original match with your 'sanitised' match.

Doing this means you don't have to be concerned with the bounding apostrophes causing complications to the check for apostrophes in the value.

Note: there may well be a perfect one-step regex to do this, but understanding that you can break tasks into several steps is useful if you spend a lot of time with regular expressions, and can help you sidestep 'perfect regex paralysis'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your string to match if there is at least one 'single quote' between your singlequote strings, then you should allow consumption of either a string which doesn't have any singlequote in it or consume if it contains two singlequotes and then you should modify your regex a bit to consume two singlequotes and add `|''` in your regex, which will now consume either non-singlequote text or a portion which has at least two singlequotes.

Try this updated regex demo and see if this works like you wanted?

https://regex101.com/r/v4nUTn/4